# connect to server option in PCMan?

Tags: raspbian, connection, file-sharing

Is there a graphical connect to server option in PCMan?
I want to drag and drop files into a server, as opposed to giving scp commands for file transfer. perhaps I'm spoiled by using nautilus and caja.

From Ubuntu: Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set up a FTP (file transfer protocol) server on your pi. A quick google search of "pi ftp" should bring up lots of options, I believe I am using `vsftpd` on mine. If you wish to use this same one, it can be installed with

`sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

Once installed, it is best to check the settings, which can be opened with

`sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`

Scroll through the list of options, setting them to your liking. When you are finished, save and restart vsftpd with

`sudo service vsftpd restart`

Now is the fun part. You should now be able to go to "Connect to server" in nautilus and type in

`ftp://user@yourlocalip`

substituting user for your user, and yourlocalip with your pi's ip address.
Drag n' drop away!

Alternatively, this can also be viewed in your browser by entering the same line above into your address location.
This should bring you to something like this:
[image of ftp client http://cdn.altrn.tv/s/99f9374c-b403-df11-8cae-0022190f5762_8_full.png?format=jpg&width=1900](http://cdn.altrn.tv/s/99f9374c-b403-df11-8cae-0022190f5762_8_full.png?format=jpg&width=1900)

At this screen, downloading files is supported. If you would like to upload, firefox (personally I use firefox, I am sure Chrome has add-ons as well) has a great little add-on called `fireFTP` which can be found in the firefox app store.(It is free) After adding this, all you have to do is right click while on your new ftp server and choose "View this page in FireFTP," which will bring you to something like this:
[image: image of FireFTP client]
<sub>(source: [mozdev.org](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/images/fireftp.png))</sub>
From here, you can download, upload, browse, I have even read about streaming, though I have not tried this myself.